# Mirrored object stays in the same place

Tags: mirror

I try to mirror an *object* **[ correction: Lamp ]** along global axis, yet it stays same place no metter what axis I choose.

Anyone has any idea why this might happen?

Edit: Object is slightly offset from global Y axis, so what I expect is to see it on the other side of axis when I mirror it, but it stays in same place.

I wanted to go from this:
[image]

To this, in one step:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: where is the object origin?

Comment: It was at median point, that didn't work, then I've selected 3D Cursor, at the bottom menu and selected a cursor point at the Y axis, then mirrored. That worked.

Comment: I also note that axis mirroring or scaling does not work on lamps. But scale, scale -1 is ok (without specifying an axis), A bug ?

Comment: So it's just a "lamp" thing? probably a bug then.

Comment: Bogac, I don't understand what are you mean or what you are doing that you expect to "mirror the lamp"?

Answer (score 1):

I did what I wanted to achieve by setting Pivot Point to 3D cursor and then mirroring. Still doesn't make sense to me, when I execute a mirror around a global axis I expect to see my object on the other side of that global axis, without playing with pivot point.

**EDIT:**

Please check this screen shot, 3D manipulator widget has an orientation selector (in this case selected to Global) and Mirror Transform also has an Orientation selector (Local). What are their effect for mirror transform. 3D manipulator has an effect at all?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a plane or any other dummy object that represents Y axis and chose it as *Mirror Object* in modifier's settings. Then you can just make it invisible if you are not to apply the modifier.

[image]

Comment: Note that one can't add modifier to a lamp object; you can go with constraint though, e.g. Copy location and invert it relatively to a dummy object in the scene.